# Magento 2: can't access pub/media files

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

Site can't access img, JS and CSS files separated in pub/media folder. But pub/static files are accessible.

I have following config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mage2.loc
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mage2
   <Directory /var/www/mage2>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself. All media files were in such form: http://localhost/pub/media/styles.css . I forgot during console installation to add param: --base_url=http://mydomain.loc